# Software to play FM radio from a USB 2.0 Digital DVB-T SDR+DAB+FM HDTV TV Tuner Receiver Stick

Tags: windows, radio

I have a USB 2.0 Digital DVB-T SDR+DAB+FM HDTV TV Tuner Receiver Stick model (RTL2832U+R820T2) and wish to listen to FM radio via my PC, however I seem not to be able to find the right software to do this.

It looks like this

[image: usb dsbfm]

With DVB and HDTV I can easily do it with SichboPVR, unfortunately this does not work with FM radio, and the software that came with package is very buggy and it only scans successfully once, then the next time it won't pick the radio stations.

So please can you help me with the right software (free/paid) that I can use to lsten to FM radio via the USB FM Tuner Reciever Stick.

Answer (score 1):

Nextpvr is one of the easiest softwares to setup and use for anything 
like this https://www.nextpvr.com/

It doesn't list a separate FM tuner since this is really just a feature of the analog tuner. ie, go to the Settings->Devices screen, double click the 'Analog' device, then hit the 'Add FM' button.

Comment: Upvoted! will accept once I try. Thaks